# I am trying to solve the integral $\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{z^2 + r^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the following integrals: 
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{z^2 + r^2}
$$
and
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{(z^2 + r^2)^{3/2}}
$$

My first attempt was to use $u=\sqrt{z^2+r^2}$ and go from there but this did not work. I tried this because this worked for the integral: 
$$
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dz e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2 + r^2}}
$$
which eventually lead to a $2K_0(mr)$ where $K_0$ is the modified bessel function of second order.

I also tried typing them in Mathematica but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Andres

Comment: Hi Andres, maybe you could try to differentiate the integral with respect to $m$ !

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Do you mean integrate? That works for the first integral (thanks!) but not for the second since that involves integrating K_0 twice!

Comment: He's talking about the Feynman trick.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define for $s\geq 0$ an integer (assuming $\alpha>0$)
$$
I^\alpha_s(x)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\exp(-x\sqrt{\alpha^2+z^2})}{(\alpha^2+z^2)^{s/2}}dz
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{d I_s^\alpha}{dx} = -I^{\alpha}_{s-1}
$$
Moreover,
$$
I_0^\alpha = 
\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-x\sqrt{\alpha^2+z^2})dz
$$
Change the variable to $z=\alpha\sinh \theta$, then $\sqrt{\alpha^2+z^2}=\alpha\cosh \theta$ and  $dz=\alpha\cosh \theta d\theta$, leading to
$$
I^\alpha_0(x)=\alpha \int_0^\infty \exp[-\alpha x\cosh \theta]\cosh \theta d\theta=\alpha K_1(\alpha x)$$
where $K_1$ is the exponentially decaying modified Bessel function. The integrals your are looking for are basically the $s$th-antiderivative (for you $s=1,2,3$) of $K_1$.

Comment: To compute these antiderivatives we also need $I_s^\alpha (0)=\int_0^\infty (\alpha^2+z^2)^{-s/2}dz$, which again can be evaluated with $z=\alpha\sinh\theta$. This does require integrating integer powers of $\operatorname{sech}z$, but that can be done recursively with a slight variant of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Higher_odd_powers_of_secant).

Comment: Hi Hamed, thanks a lot for your answer!

The problem with finding the anti-derivative is that it works find for s=1 and s=2, but if you do it again for s=3, you end up with the integral of 1/2 \[Pi] z (BesselK[0, z] StruveL[-1, z] + 
   BesselK[1, z] StruveL[0, z]), where StruveL is the modified Struve function.

Comment: @Andres If, for your second integral, you use integration by parts with $u=e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}},dv=\frac {dz}{(z^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$, you'll have
\begin{align}\frac1{r^2}\frac z{\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\Bigg\vert_{-\infty}^\infty-\frac1{r^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac z{\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\frac{-mz}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\,dz\\
&=\frac m{r^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bigg(1-\frac{r^2}{r^2+z^2}\bigg)e^{-m\sqrt{z^2+r^2}}\,dz,
\end{align}so it can be evaluated in terms of Hamed's $I_0$ and $I_2$.

Comment: Hi Antonio, this is great! Thanks, I think this actually works!Best wishes,

Comment: For the record. Antonio's answer was the one that worked the best!